# RODBC and unicode on Windows

Tags: r, windows, encoding, rodbc

In our organisation we use primarily Microsoft software on Windows machines. We're using R and Shiny to display data for users by retrieving MS SQL data using RODBC. Problem I'm having, is that it doesn't retrieve unicode characters correctly. Japanese characters get displayed as ???????. I believe reason for this is because locale of Windows machines is cp1252. I've set DBMSencoding to UTF-8 in RODBC function, set system locale to UTF-8 (Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")) and used iconv to convert to UTF-8, but all to no avail.

I've been doing quite a bit of research on this, but have had no luck so far. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or there's a limitation in the function. Can you give me any suggestions, or point me in the right direction perhaps. I can use RJDBC which does work, but that one is awfully slow as it uses Java.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried the following: `odbcConnect(dsn, uid, pwd, DBMSencoding = 'UTF8')`, to directly translate on import? Alternative packages: `odbc` combined with `DBI` works well with similar to better performance than `RODBC`.

Comment: Hi Oliver, yes I have included that in the DBMSencoding. I haven't looked at odbc, so will definitely give that a try, thanks!

Comment: no problem. A quick guide for the two packages. Simply using `ch <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = dsn, pwd = pwd, encoding = encoding)` where `pwd`, `dsn` and `encoding` are replaced with their respective code, will activate a connection, which can then be used with the `DBI` package functions. `odbc()` should (in all cases I've tried) automatically choose a compatible driver.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I tried using odbc with encoding set to latin1 and UTF-8, trying to display this text 大和ハウス工業株式会社, but unfortunately both show ?????? as well.

Comment: [Link](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/301) to corresponding bug